# Perl secure session

Tags: perl, session-cookies

I was wondering if there is any way of setting the session cookie (CGISESSID) attribute isSecure to true in Perl? I know at least in php it is easy to with:

`ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);`

Is there some similar way to do this in Perl?

Crossposted to [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1152170).

Comment: Perl is a general purpose programming language. Session support is not a core feature, but something you add on with code (usually a CPAN module). How you set the secure flag on a session id cookie would depend on the library (or your own manual code) that you are using.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1152170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you use CGI::Cookie to build your cookie and $headers is a  HTTP::Headers object you could use the following code:

```
require CGI::Cookie;
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(
    -name => 'testcookie', -value => 'testvalue', -secure => 1);
$headers->push_header(set_cookie => $cookie->as_string);
```

+- typos

HTH

Comment: Some additional information that I forgot to mention in the original post:
The session cookie is set with CGI::Session not with CGI::Cookie. I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation on how to set the session's secure flag to true. Is this possible?

Comment: If i get you right, you are using    print $session->header() to get your cookie set. According to the docs you could use instead:  $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>$session->name, -value=>$session->id, -secure => 1 ); print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie, @_);

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.